# Grappling hook joint won't hook onto a game object Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've started trying to code a grappling hook in unity but my distance joint won't hook onto the gameobject but rather blank space. I want to make it so that my distance joint will hook onto the gameobject instead of blank space. I feel that maybe there is a problem with the joint vectors but I don't know.

Here's my code:

```cs
public class Grapplescript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer line;
    DistanceJoint2D joint;
    Vector3 targetPos;
    RaycastHit2D hit;
    public float distance = 10f;
    public LayerMask mask;
    public float step = 0.02f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        joint = GetComponent<DistanceJoint2D>();
        joint.enabled = false;
        line.enabled = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (joint.distance > .5f)
            joint.distance -= step;
        else
        {
            line.enabled = false;
            joint.enabled = false;

        }


        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))
        {
            targetPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            targetPos.z = 0;

            hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, targetPos - transform.position, distance, mask);

            if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() != null)

            {
                joint.enabled = true;
                //  Debug.Log (hit.point - new Vector2(hit.collider.transform.position.x,hit.collider.transform.position.y);
                Vector2 connectPoint = hit.point - new Vector2(hit.collider.transform.position.x, hit.collider.transform.position.y);
                connectPoint.x = connectPoint.x / hit.collider.transform.localScale.x;
                connectPoint.y = connectPoint.y / hit.collider.transform.localScale.y;
                Debug.Log(connectPoint);
                joint.connectedAnchor = connectPoint;

                joint.connectedBody = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                //      joint.connectedAnchor = hit.point - new Vector2(hit.collider.transform.position.x,hit.collider.transform.position.y);
                joint.distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, hit.point);

                line.enabled = true;
                line.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
                line.SetPosition(1, hit.point);

                //reference to another code
                line.GetComponent<roperatio>().grabPos = hit.point;


            }
        }
        //line.SetPosition(1, joint.connectedBody.transform.TransformPoint(joint.connectedAnchor));

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse1))
        {

            line.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        }


        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse1))
        {
            joint.enabled = false;
            line.enabled = false;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "blank space" specifically?

Comment: I mean the line would connect between three player and the game objects I was targeting but the fixed joint wouldn’t go where I clicked and rather somewhere else that I didn’t want it to be. When I tried it out it seemed to always go out to the right of the target and not usually hit the game objects. Not necessarily a blank space but just not on target. Apologies for that. I’m maininly just having trouble with making the fixed joint go on target rather than miss all of the time.